# Get the computer name instead of the DNS name using IP adress

Tags: c#, .net, server

I have the following code:

```
public static string GetHostname(string sIP) {
    // GetServerIP(sIP)[0] is the IP of the server
    string? sHostname = GetServerIP(sIP)[0];
    IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(sHostname);

    return host.HostName.ToString()!;       
}
```

The ip address is correct but the name returned is not (in my case) "server" but "MeinServer.speedport.ip", which is odd because the server has a static ip address. The name returned is the one used by the router.

When I use ping in cmd with the IP I get the correct name, so why not with the function?

How do I get the correct computer name and not the dns name of the router, without changing the name in the router (in this case 'server')?

Comment: It's doing a `PTR` reverse lookup, which in your case returns the public DNS name for that IP address, it has no knowledge of your internal server unless it's querying your internal DNS

Answer (score 1):

As by [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentry?view=net-6.0), the behaviour is as expected:

> The GetHostEntry method queries a DNS server for the IP addresses and aliases associated with an IP address.

You might want to try this: `System.Environment.MachineName`

which returns the NETBIOS name of the local machine. See [MachineName docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Unfortunately this only works on a local machine, since I got the IP address MachineName would just return the name of the local machine, because MachineName cannot take a IP adress as a parameter

Comment: Can you explain what you want in one sentence?

Comment: I want to get the name of the server, which I named "Server" (the PC that is my server) and not the name i have given the PC in the router, which is MeinServer: longh sentence short, I want it to return "server" and not "MeinServer.speedport.ip"

Comment: From which machine?

Comment: As I said... I have my computer which runs the command, getting the IP (192.168.2.109 - the server), I want the name of the server not the name in the router -- server-name is SERVER, router-dns-name is MEINSERVER(.speedport.ip) I want the SERVER name